How do I query posts by meta_query OR tag_query?
I've got a shared taxonomy "represented_country" between 'post' type and 'artist' type. I'd like to search for all related posts for the current 'artist' displayed.
Used alone, the meta query works well and fetches all posts that have an 'artist_related' meta related to the current artist ID displayed.

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'artist_related',
            'value' => get_the_ID(),
            'compare' => '='
        )
    ));


Each Artist is also related to a country. I've got a "represented_country" taxonomy for all post type 'post'. I'd like to query allthese posts type 'post' that are also related to a given country, though the "represented_country" taxonomy. With a OR between, so that if the taxonomy query returns nothing, I can still rely on the meta query.
Here is what my query looks like (but it returns nothing):
$args = array(
     'post_type' => 'post',
     'meta_query' => array(
         array(
             'key' => 'escaf_artist_related',
             'value' => get_the_ID(),
             'compare' => '='
         )
     ),
     'relation' => 'OR',
     'tax_query' => array(
         array(
             'taxonomy' => 'represented_country',
             'field' => 'term_id',
             'terms' => 'belgique'
         )
     ) );

